# Animating UIBarButtonItem witdth

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I've got a navigation bar with multiple left bar button items. They are buttons that have fixed size as long as they are not selected. If a button is selected, it needs to be expanded (by animating its width), and buttons to the right of the selected button need to move right to not overlap with the expanded one.

Here's how I'm trying to do it right now:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:button
                  duration:0.25
                   options:0
                animations:^{
                    button.frame = /* changing height here */;
                    button.selected = YES;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                }];
```

However, as I select a button, its siblings stay where they were, so the buttons overlap.

What should I do so that animation of one button causes other buttons to animate too?

Comment: Have you updated the bar button item's `width` property?

Comment: Damn, no! I'll give it a try!

Comment: Let me know if it works and I will add an answer. ;-)

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you not redraw navigation bar to take new button's frame into effect in your completion block?